# Get NuGet.exe version from command-line

Tags: command-line, version, nuget

I'd like to get the `NuGet.exe` version using the command-line.

I know I can get the version of NuGet running as part of Visual Studio, as per the instructions [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/nuget-faq#How_do_I_check_the_exact_version_of_NuGet_installed?), but what I'm after is something similar from the command-line, i.e like:

`nuget --version`

Any ideas?

Comment: In a particular programming language, or just in general?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Typing `nuget help` from the command line will in addition to the expected help information also list the current NuGet.exe version.

Comment: try `nuget help | head -1` for a single line result.

Comment: Or `nuget help | select -First 1` if you're on Windows (PowerShell).

Comment: Any idea why that powershell command gives an exit code of 1?

Comment: @ThetaSinner: The PowerShell command `nuget help | select -First 1` works just fine and returns the current NuGet version. If you're having problems a bit more context is needed to help you (and it probably belongs in a separate question as well).

Comment: A comment accompanying the down-vote would be highly appreciated, perhaps event with an edit suggestion to improve the answer...

Answer (score 62):

To know which version of NuGet is installed use follow steps

- In Visual Studio, use the *Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio* command and look at the version displayed next to *NuGet Package Manager*.
- Alternatively, launch the *Package Manager Console* (*Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console*) and enter `$host` to see information about NuGet including the version.

Comment: displaying different versions in About: NuGet Package Manager   4.6.0 and 
Console: Package Manager Host 4.7.0.5212

Comment: The same with me @volody, the first option in my case gives "**4.6.0**" also, and the second option "**4.9.2.5706**". It would seem that the version details are not in sync? [This page from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/policies/nuget-faq#nuget-in-visual-studio) also suggests the same as this answer.

Answer (score 12):

**Windows Powershell:**

```
nuget help | select -First 1
```

[image]

---

**Cmd.exe**

```
nuget ?
```

[image]

---

**Not working anymore**

> Command line (cmd.exe) | Package Manager Console in Visual Studio
>
> ```
> 1.) nuget ? v
> 2.) nuget help v
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> The "v" command is actually not valid, but with this approach you only
> get the nuget version number and below the information that "v" is an
> unknow command.

Comment: interestingly enough, v actually triggers nuget verify now in newer versions, (tested with 4.9.3.5777) and is no longer an unknown command

Answer (score 4):

In the `.NET 6` era, I use this command to see version of Nuget:

```
dotnet nuget --version
```

It will reply something like this:

```
NuGet Command Line
6.2.0.146
```

Works identically on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

**On Windows 10 CMD console**, try this:

C:>nuget help |findstr "NuGet Version"

**On Windows 10 PowerShell console**, try this:

PS C:> nuget help | select -First 1

Both of them will return something like:

NuGet Version: 5.8.1.7021

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works perfect if tweaked correctly:
It should read `nuget help | findstr /C:"NuGet Version"`

Answer (score 0):

I had his very question, in my Centos7 Docker container.

This is how I solved it:

```
yum info nuget
```

`yum info nuget` returns a great deal! Just wanting the numbers, I added a `grep` and a `sed` to clean things up.

```
yum info nuget | grep Version | sed 's/^.*: //'
```

To put in in a variable in your bash script:

```
nuget_version=$(yum info nuget | grep Version | sed 's/^.*: //')
```